# The way to use 3 figures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am trying to put 3 figures in this format:
[image]

but they appear like this:
[image]

I am using this code:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{subfigmatrix}{2}
        \subfigure[Dados do vento e respectiva potência por modelo de turbina]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{Figures/tabvento.png}}
        \subfigure[Perfil de vento típico da ilha da Brava]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/perfilvento.png}}
        \subfigure[Curva de potência dos 2 modelos de aerogeradores]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Figures/curvaaero.png}}
    \end{subfigmatrix}
    \caption[Dados gerais do recurso eólico utilizado para as simulações]{Dados gerais do recurso eólico utilizado para as simulações}
    \label{fig:irrfdad}
\end{figure}
```

Any suggestion how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a} \end{minipage}& \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image} \\ \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image} \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}
        \caption{Hello\label{fig:irrfdad}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's nice thank you, but the two images at right are sticked. It´s possible to define a margin between each?

Comment: Yes, just put a distance between square brackets following the double backslash, e.g. \\\[1in]

Comment: Nice thanks it worked! Just another question, it's possible to define a subcaption to each of the figures just like i showed initially ?

Comment: You can do it manually, by putting text between two pairs of double backslashes.  Use \centering to get it centered.